# The support of a real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Find the supp($f_i$) for:

1) $f_1=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. The rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so the support will be $\mathbb{R}$.

2)$f_2 =x$ . So $f_2(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ so $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f_2(x)\neq0 \}= [-\infty,0) \cup (0,+\infty]$ and the closure of this set is $\mathbb{R}$.

3) $f_3 =$ max$\{0,x\}$. So $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f_3(x)\neq0 \} = (0,+\infty]$ and the closure of this set is $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

4) $f_4 = e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(x)$. Then $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:f_3(x)\neq0 \} = (-1,1)$ and the closure is $[-1,1]$

Are my toughts on this correct?

Comment: If by $\mathbb{R}^+$ you mean $[0, +\infty)$, everything is correct.

Comment: yes, should be correct

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your help and quick answer! :)